# Java - un jar a jar file throws error

Tags: java

I am trying unjar a particular jar file, eg: abcd.jar using following command

```
jar -xvf abcd.jar
```

but it throws below error

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 2388918280 but got 320 bytes)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:373)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:714)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:677)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:189)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:903)
```

I need to unjar this jar file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's corrupt. Reacquire it.

Answer (score 0):

The jar is corrupt and you can not do anything about it. You will have to get another one. This jar is useless now